MYSQL CONNECTOR PYTHON
tengo este codigo y soy el unico de mi salon al que no le conecta la BD. Me arroja en VSCODE un error de exit code 1 y en PyCharm me arroja exit code -1073741819 (0xc00005). Ya reinstale workbench, mysql, python, la libreria de mysql-connector pero sigue sin funcionar.
Con este codigo no me funciona:
import mysql.connector

connection = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='root',
    password='madrid2020',
    database='persona_bd'
)

Pero con este si:
from mysql.connector import connection


persona_db = connection.MySQLConnection(
    host = 'localhost',
    user = 'root',
    password = 'madrid2020',
    database = 'persona_bd'
)


¿Probastes con un usuario que no fuera root?

No, la verdad solo probe con el usuario root como en el curso, a mis compañeros les anduvo excepto a mi, no se cual puede ser el problema

mysql-connector es un paquete que ya no recibe actualizaciones. La misma descripción dice que deberías utilizar mysql-connector-python.
Prueba eliminar la versión vieja y obtener la última con los siguientes comandos:
pip uninstall mysql-connector
pip install --upgrade mysql-connector-python


Si, perdon. Tengo instalado el paquete de mysql-connector-python, y tambien actualice el pip. Lo extraño es que soy el unico del salon al que no le anda, todos los demas si
